# How to pipe html to gedit with format/spacing?

Tags: gnome, application-development, python

Is there a way to pipe html to gedit witout losing the spacing.

I am trying with: `echo "'+html5template+'" | gedit`

The output is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
            <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
 </html>
```

The script look like this:

```
doctype='<!DOCTYPE html>'
html_start='<html>'
header_start='<head>'
header_end='</head>'
body='<body></body>'
html_end='</html>'

meta_data=''

#get page title
meta_data += '<title>'+self.builder.get_object("page_title_entry").get_text()+'</title>'

#build the html template
html5template=doctype+html_start+header_start+meta_data+header_end+body+html_end

#open template with gedit
Popen('echo "'+html5template+'" | gedit', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create any spacing in your Python code, your output is exactly what your Python code creates.

To get the spacing you want you can for example replace

```
html5template=doctype+html_start+header_start+meta_data+header_end+body+html_end
```

with

```
indent='    '    
html5template='\n'.join((doctype,
                        html_start,
                        indent + header_start,
                        indent + indent + meta_data,
                        indent + header_end,
                        indent + body,
                        html_end
                        ))
```